# How to extract emails from a list of folders where the email is into the folder name in windows?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of folders that has those names variations:
(there are around 700 folders, so manually is not an option)

```
 name name name - email@email.com
 name name name - email@email.com + email@email.com + email@email.com + email@email.com
```

take care about this: between the name and the email always exists:

```
 " - "
```

between emails, when exists always exists:

```
 " + "
```

I would like to take the

"name name name" and assign all the emails for each name in an excel sheet.

I think I need a batch to loop all folders, get the folder name, extract the name, extract the emails and write down in a text file. For repeted email I would like to have a another row, so each name has a single email. The names might be repeated but they refer to different emails.

Then from the text file I have to convert to a excel file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I assume you're looking for a solution in windows/command/poweshell?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I just want a simple solution.. excel vb file or something like this is fine too

Comment: do you mean FILES instead of Folders? (so you have a folder that has Files conforming to the described names?)

Comment: only folders.. I have a root folder that has 700 folders into it. What I need is their names and then some crops in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these two command from the commandline in the directory where your direxctory tre starts.

```
for /D   %a in (*.*) do @echo %a >> dlist.txt

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=-" %a in (dlist.txt) do @echo "%a" ; "%b" >> emails.csv
```

Comment: thanks but i make a new file: "run this.cmd" and then edit, pasted your answer and then doubleclick. It doesn't generate any file... :S how to make it work? thanks again ;)

Comment: You can nest the `for`s – there is no need for a temporary file to lie around. Also you're generating invalid CSV.

Comment: this is not generating anything in my win vista... ran as admin too. no luck

Comment: @Totty I did run the commands direct from the command line. You should run it from the directory where your email directories are. The first commonad should give you a dlist.txt that holds your directories, the second should generate the emails.csv. @Joey How would you do it because I have no clue on how to limit the file-set in /F to just directories (which is what the OP asked for).

Comment: If you run it in a batch file you'll need to use `%%a` rather than `%a`.

Comment: rene: `for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=-" %a in ('for /d %x in (*) do @echo %x') do ...` something akin to that.

Comment: @Joey: for is not command, just tried it after your first comment :-)

Comment: You might need some escaping. `cmd` is picky at times, especially in such cases. I just tend to avoid temporary files if I can help it ;)

Comment: I just done it with VBA in excel.. dirty but it works, I will post in a answer

Answer (score 1):

In VBA for the Excel paste this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFileNames()
Dim i As Integer
Dim fso As Object, folder As Object, subfolder As Object
i = 0


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\****\Desktop\****")

For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    ActiveCell.Offset(i) = subfolder.Name
    i = i + 1
Next subfolder
```

End Sub

- Select the first col, first row
- Then click run, to run the VBA command
- This will create all the rows with the name of the folders
- Then in the B, use this formula: "=LOCALIZAR(" - ";A2)"
- In C: "=NÚM.CARACT(A2)"
- In D: "=SEG.TEXTO(A2;1;B2)"
- In E: "=SEG.TEXTO(A2;B2 + 3;C2)"
- In F: "=SUBST(E2;" + ";", ")"

In D you will get the name, and in F you will get all the emails separated by ", ".
That's all!